# Set invalid status to reactive form control

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to set a form control status to invalid, but this example doesn't work

```
this.currencyForm.controls['currencyMaxSell'].setErrors({smallerThan: true})
```

Comment: It's supposed to work this way. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I'm using   "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0", "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1", in Plunker only 2.0.0-beta17

Comment: Plunker provides a template for the newest Angular2 version. Just use the "new" button and select "Angular"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i find why don't update, doesn't chnage value . Thanks.

Comment: but now cant delete that error, find method setErrors but some method like deletError can't fund

Comment: What about uding setErrors and passing `null`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why would anyone like to set formControl as invalid witout a validator but here's how you do this `this.myForm.controls['mycontrolname'].setErrors({});`.

**You should use [validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) and set control invalid this way**

Comment: I can give you a very good example. Imagine you have a dropdown list and an input field. The drop down list provides you with a manufacturer. the input field is there for giving an item of this manufacturer a name. The rule is, that a name has to be unique among all items of the same manufacturer. if you first choose the manufacturer and then enter an item's name, the validation will complain if the name is already in use. but what if you enter a non existing name and then change the manufacturer again? if the item's name is in use then, the validator of the name's input will not warn you.

Comment: @Lynx242 you should use a validator on a formGroup (or any parent control) and do the validation there. You can access both those fields in validator and set errors accordingly.

Comment: Okay. Will have a look on it. I thought that validators are only FormControl-bound.